# Java Integer underflow / overflow not happen during math operation?

Tags: java, math, integer, overflow, underflow

Could someone explain me, why `a` is equals `2'147'483'647` ?

```
int a = (int)(3434 * 2353253.0)
```

Why is this "sticking to Integer.MAX_VALUE" happening?
I expected some integer overflow behavior and a result of `-508'863'790`

(openjdk 11.0.16.1 2022-08-12)

Comment: There is no `int`-value that is `< Integer.MIN_VALUE`, and there is no `int`-value that is `> Integer.MAX_VALUE`. --- I do not see how the code presented is related to the question. Please [edit] the post and clarify.

Comment: It sounds like you want to verify that the intermediate result neither underflows nor overflows `int`. When you [edit] your question, please cite/recapitulate the original problem.

Comment: Hi all, I edited my post and reduced it to it's underlying question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because the [Java language](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/jls17.pdf) says it must.  See section 5.1.3,  Narrowing Primitive Conversion.

> Otherwise, if the floating-point number is not an infinity, the
> floating-point value is rounded to an integer value V using the round
> toward zero rounding policy (§4.2.4). Then there are two cases:
> a. If
> T is long, and this integer value can be represented as a long, then
> the result of the first step is the long value V.
> b. Otherwise, if
> this integer value can be represented as an int, then the result of
> the first step is the int value V.
> • Otherwise, one of the following
> two cases must be true:
> a. The value must be too small (a negative
> value of large magnitude or negative infinity), and the result of the
> first step is the smallest representable value of type int or long.
> b.
> The value must be too large (a positive value of large magnitude or
> positive infinity), and the result of the first step is the largest
> representable value of type int or long

This last clause is what you are witnessing in action.

Comment: Direct link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3